# Play 2.0.8 How to get FilePart from MultipartFormData?

Tags: java, html, playframework, playframework-2.0

the can not get the file by play form type. and 
The view html is:

```
<div data-role="appviewpage" data-title="Upload Scenario Config">
    <div data-role="content">

        <form action="/upload/configfile.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="file" name="picture">

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="save">
            </p>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the application function is:

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Text.class, maxLength = 100 * 1024)
    public static Result uploadConfigFile() {
        Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");

        if (picture != null) {
          String fileName = picture.getFilename();
          String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
          File file = picture.getFile();
          return ok("File uploaded");
        } else {
            return ok("this is not support now");
        }

    }
```

and the mapper is :

```
POST   /upload/configfile.html          controllers.Application.uploadConfigFile()
```

but the response is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at controllers.Application.uploadConfigFile(Application.java:340)
```

Comment: Did you set your form enctype to multipart/formdata ?

Comment: i modify the information .but , i cant get the file

Answer (score 0):

I got very similar issue, but on play 2.2.0.

Try add in your view html this statement : **'enctype -> "multipart/form-data"**
For example:

```
@form(routes.Application.uploadConfigFile(), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data"){
..
<input type="file" name="picture">

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</p>
...
}
```

Edit:
I see @Musa was first :)

Comment: i do as your advise, but get the same error like before.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at controllers.Application.uploadConfigFile(Application.java:340)